# How to remove circular reference in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm

The circular reference between my Customer and Order entities caused a exception during serialization. Is there any way to force EF to generate one-direction reference between these two entities? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When I need to serialize, I generally project onto other types. This eliminates circular references, plus other data I don't want serialize. For example:

```
var q = (from c in Repository.Customers()
         where c.Id == id
         select new 
         {
             Name = c.Name,
             Orders = from o in C.Orders
                      select new
                      {
                          Date = o.Date
                      }
         }).First();
return Json(q);
```

Answer (score 5):

When you create an association in model designer (right click add->association) you'll get a popup windows which looks like this:

[image: Add association window]

Notice the navigation property check boxes, you can deselect them if you don't want them to be generated. To solve your circular reference problem, make sure only one or none are checked, not both.

Comment: Sorry, I can't catch up what you said. Can you put it more specify? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Charlie, but I cann't see the picture. And my designer don't have checkbox on it. :( I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Ok, I'm using Entity Framework 4.0 on VS2010 beta 2...maybe this isn't something you can do in the older version of EF.

Comment: In 3.5 SP1 you can't remove navigation properties using the designer, you have to resort to removing them from the ConceptualModel section of the XML inside the EDMX file. However I think Craig's answer is much better. You don't necessarily want to change you model to solve a serialization problem. There is only so much you can do by changing the model.

Comment: @Charlie, James: Thanks a lot. I'm going to add Dto to my project.

Comment: @Alex James. Yep I'll go with that as well, Craigs solution is preferable

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this problem in EF 3.5 By changing the Child's navigation property Getter from public to Internal.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Not entirely sure if it's the right way to do it though!

Answer (score 1):

On serverlevel:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.isreference%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Watch this page
I hope I could do to survive
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The changing getter to internal for a child navigation worked for me with entitfy framework v5/v6 under Web API v2

Comment: it fixed the web api help but killed the serialization